# Purpose of giving up a prisoner on the Passover

Tags: life-of-jesus

Why did they give over a prisoner during the Passover? What was the reason for that

Comment: Hi Beverly, welcome to Christianity.SE.  This is a good question, but not necessarily for this site; this site is focused on Christian doctrine.  It might be better for you to ask this question on [History.SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/), where you'd be more likely to get good answers about the historical context in which the Romans thought it was a good idea to make a practice of releasing a prisoner to the Jews on one of their holy days.

Comment: Who is they and who are they in regards to Christianity?

Comment: Beverly is referring to Pilate asking the Jews about which prisoner to release during passover @TheFreemason

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about Christian beliefs, practices or church history.

Comment: Agreed, better asked on Judaism.SE.  Just for the fun of it: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3262626?uid=3739840&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21106524350933

Answer (score 0):

Like many judicial systems, the Roman legal system had provisions for pardoning of crime. It is likely the appointed time for pardon appeals coincided with the passover because that was the time many of the Jews in the region came to the city. In other words, it was politically expedient for the governing officials to grant a request before the largest audience of each the year.

(Not unlike how politicians today use "phtot-ops" at events with large public appeal, but then sign lesser received legislation on Fridays right after all the press goes home for the weekend...)